# How many time a function is called in Trace32?

Tags: function, time, trace32, lauterbach

I have only debugger power-pro from Lauterbach. I can't do trace with it, is it normal ?

And if it's normal, I need to know how can I know how many time a function is called ? I set a breakpoint on my function but it doesn't show the same number when I use trace.statistic during the same time (the count is not the same).

Comment: What METHOD is selected in the window Trace.state? (Menu > Trace > Configuration...)

Comment: @Holger I tested ONCHIP but i can't select Analyser or CAnalyzer. This two options are not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Trace.METHOD ONCHIP ist selected, your chip actually supports some trace functionality. The program flow is stored in a dedicated memory on the chip and read from there via JTAG.
(The methods Analyser or CAnalyzer apply to Lauterbach hardware, which can store the program flow when it is send from the chip via a dedicated physical interface.)

The on-chip trace buffer is probably not very big. So when it overflows it will either stop recording or overwrite the oldest data. So your on-chip buffer can only record a certain amount of executed instructions.
So watch in the Window `Trace.state` how your trace buffer fills up.

If you are only interested how much one single function is called, I recommend to record only the call of this function. Therefor program a trace-filter in your chip. You can do this with the command `Break.Set <your function's name> /TraceEnable`. Although the command sounds like "setting a breakpoint", it is instead programming a trace filter thanks to the option "/TraceEnable"

Next, clear your trace buffer with `Trace.Init`, run your code until it hits your breakpoint and open `Trace.STATistic.sYmbol Count /CountALL`, which shows you how often your function was called. Ensure that (even with the active filter) your trace buffer does not overflow while your application is running.

---

If you can't use the on-chip trace you could create a variable e.g. with `Var.NEWGLOBAL int \count=0` and set a breakpoint on your function's entry which increments the counting variable every time the breakpoint gets hit. E.g. like this: `Break.set myFuncName /CMD "Var.ASSIGN \count++" /RESUME` . Watch the counting variable with `Var.View %e \count`.

Comment: I have an error "no trace licence, onchip trace is limited to 5 minutes". I do the same as you written me and i have still a problem.

Comment: And i have an other answer, how i can write a script who do that ? And how i can stop the execution when on-chip buffer is full please ?

Comment: If you want to use the onchip trace, you actually require a trace license. Sorry, I haven't considered that. Since trace is definitely the best solution for your problem I think you should consider to buy such a license.

Comment: Without trace you could create a variable e.g. with `Var.NEWGLOBAL int \count=0` and set a breakpoint on your function's entry which increments your variable each time it gets hit. E.g. like this: `Break.set myFuncName /CMD "Var.ASSIGN \count++"  /RESUME`. Watch the variable with `Var.View %e \count`

Comment: About writing script for TRACE32 please see https://www.lauterbach.com/pdf/training_practice.pdf

Comment: Stopping the program execution of the CPU on a full on-chip trace buffer is pretty tricky if you want to stop the CPU exactly at the moment when the trace buffer is full, since it requires an advanced programming of the trigger resources on your chip. It depends highly on the type of chip your are using if this is possible at all and how to achieve it (when possible). I suggest to contact the Lauterbach support on that.